# Changing each element in a list with differents threads

Tags: c#, concurrency, task

I have the following pseudo-code:

```
public void Associar(List<Data> dados)
{
   List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
   foreach(dado in dados)
   {
       tasks.Add(AdicionarAsync(dado));
   }
   Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

   Debug.WriteLine(dados.Select(e => e.Colecao).Sum(e => e.Count));
}

public async Task<List<Foo>> ConsultarNoBanco()
{
   //make request 
   //here the result is OK
   return result;
}

public async Task AdicionarAsync(Data dado)
{
   dado.Colecao = await ConsultarNoBanco();
   //Here the result (dado.Colecao) is wrong
   //If I modify the code to ConsultarNoBanco().Result everything works fine
}
```

The output of this code must always be 411. However, the result changes each time the method `Associar()` is called. What is the best way to use a thread safe list to change each item in a collection with multi-thread?

Comment: Try to use `Parallel.For` method.

Comment: You are not using thread. Forget threads. [There is no thread.](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Comment: Use [ConcurrentBag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx) or synchronization when you modify you non thread safe collection.

Comment: @Maarten you are right. I'm using tasks

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan the result still the same with concurrent bag. I updated the question with some details in the comment of the code.

Comment: @João Paulo, I can't see in method Associar task starting. I think it's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Parallel.ForEach();` to modify entries in your list.
It will manage concurrency and threading for you.

You can also `break` by using `e.Break();`

Answer (score 0):

The current answer(s)/comment(s) are saying something that you need to manage concurrency since you are modifying entries in your list using tasks/threading. IMHO this is incorrect since the modifications that are being done on your `Data` object are fine - each task is only modifying the designated `Data` object. No synchronization is necessary at that point.

On the other hand, your method `ConsultarNoBanco` is being executed from multiple tasks/threads, *at the same time*. Since you are not showing the code in the method, we cannot say anything about it. But it is my impression that this method is not thread-safe. Especially since the method is not receiving the `Data` object, and I can therefore only assume it is doing something not related to the `Data` object.

Can you show the code of the method `ConsultarNoBanco`? Is it thread-safe? You mention a request, is the request-handler thread-safe?